SAM build can't resolve dependencies for 'onnxruntime'
My problem
Summary
I am trying to implement YOLO on AWS Lambda, and when trying to build a Lambda Layer with ONNX, I get Error: PythonPipBuilder:ResolveDependencies - {onnxruntime==1.18.1(wheel)}.
Minimal example
Here's a minimal template that reproduces the error:
AWSTemplateFormatVersion: '2010-09-09'
Transform: AWS::Serverless-2016-10-31

Resources:
  LambdaLayerOnnx:
    Type: AWS::Serverless::LayerVersion
    Properties:
      LayerName: !Sub ${AWS::StackName}-onnx
      ContentUri: lambda/layers/onnx
    Metadata:
      BuildMethod: python3.12


The requirements.txt file looks like:
onnxruntime==1.18.1 ; python_version >= "3.10" and python_version < "4.0"

When running with the --debug option, these are the logs of the important part (formatted for easier reading):
2024-06-30 23:47:04,699 | Registering workflow 'RubyBundlerBuilder' with capability 'Capability(language='ruby', dependency_manager='bundler', application_framework=None)' 
2024-06-30 23:47:04,701 | Registering workflow 'RustCargoLambdaBuilder' with capability 'Capability(language='rust', dependency_manager='cargo', application_framework=None)'
2024-06-30 23:47:04,703 | Found workflow 'PythonPipBuilder' to support capabilities 'Capability(language='python', dependency_manager='pip', application_framework=None)'
2024-06-30 23:47:04,785 | Running workflow 'PythonPipBuilder'
2024-06-30 23:47:04,786 | Running PythonPipBuilder:ResolveDependencies
2024-06-30 23:47:05,000 | calling pip download -r ~/test/lambda/layers/onnx/requirements.txt --dest /tmp/tmpt5hdp82u --exists-action i
2024-06-30 23:47:06,852 | pip stdout: b'Collecting onnxruntime==1.18.1 (from -r ~/test/lambda/layers/onnx/requirements.txt (line 1))
 Obtaining dependency information for onnxruntime==1.18.1 from https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/a3/0a/89bc7acdf7b311ec5cdf6c01983e8ecb23f7b1ba7a1b2d2fd10d33dfd24a/onnxruntime-1.18.1-cp312-cp312-manylinux_2_27_x86_64.manylinux_2_28_x86_64.whl.metadata
 Using cached onnxruntime-1.18.1-cp312-cp312-manylinux_2_27_x86_64.manylinux_2_28_x86_64.whl.metadata (4.3 kB)
Collecting coloredlogs (from onnxruntime==1.18.1->-r ~/test/lambda/layers/onnx/requirements.txt (line 1))
 Obtaining dependency information for coloredlogs from https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/a7/06/3d6badcf13db419e25b07041d9c7b4a2c331d3f4e7134445ec5df57714cd/coloredlogs-15.0.1-py2.py3-none-any.whl.metadata
 Using cached coloredlogs-15.0.1-py2.py3-none-any.whl.metadata (12 kB)
Collecting flatbuffers (from onnxruntime==1.18.1->-r ~/test/lambda/layers/onnx/requirements.txt (line 1))
 Obtaining dependency information for flatbuffers from https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/41/f0/7e988a019bc54b2dbd0ad4182ef2d53488bb02e58694cd79d61369e85900/flatbuffers-24.3.25-py2.py3-none-any.whl.metadata
 Using cached flatbuffers-24.3.25-py2.py3-none-any.whl.metadata (850 bytes)
Collecting numpy<2.0,>=1.21.6 (from onnxruntime==1.18.1->-r ~/test/lambda/layers/onnx/requirements.txt (line 1))
 Obtaining dependency information for numpy<2.0,>=1.21.6 from https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/0f/50/de23fde84e45f5c4fda2488c759b69990fd4512387a8632860f3ac9cd225/numpy-1.26.4-cp312-cp312-manylinux_2_17_x86_64.manylinux2014_x86_64.whl.metadata
 Using cached numpy-1.26.4-cp312-cp312-manylinux_2_17_x86_64.manylinux2014_x86_64.whl.metadata (61 kB)
Collecting packaging (from onnxruntime==1.18.1->-r ~/test/lambda/layers/onnx/requirements.txt (line 1))
 Obtaining dependency information for packaging from https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/08/aa/cc0199a5f0ad350994d660967a8efb233fe0416e4639146c089643407ce6/packaging-24.1-py3-none-any.whl.metadata
 Using cached packaging-24.1-py3-none-any.whl.metadata (3.2 kB)
Collecting protobuf (from onnxruntime==1.18.1->-r ~/test/lambda/layers/onnx/requirements.txt (line 1))
 Obtaining dependency information for protobuf from https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/27/e4/8dc4546be46873f8950cb44cdfe19b79d66d26e53c4ee5e3440406257fcd/protobuf-5.27.2-cp38-abi3-manylinux2014_x86_64.whl.metadata
 Using cached protobuf-5.27.2-cp38-abi3-manylinux2014_x86_64.whl.metadata (592 bytes)
Collecting sympy (from onnxruntime==1.18.1->-r ~/test/lambda/layers/onnx/requirements.txt (line 1))
 Obtaining dependency information for sympy from https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/61/53/e18c8c97d0b2724d85c9830477e3ebea3acf1dcdc6deb344d5d9c93a9946/sympy-1.12.1-py3-none-any.whl.metadata
 Using cached sympy-1.12.1-py3-none-any.whl.metadata (12 kB)
Collecting humanfriendly>=9.1 (from coloredlogs->onnxruntime==1.18.1->-r ~/test/lambda/layers/onnx/requirements.txt (line 1))
 Obtaining dependency information for humanfriendly>=9.1 from https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/f0/0f/310fb31e39e2d734ccaa2c0fb981ee41f7bd5056ce9bc29b2248bd569169/humanfriendly-10.0-py2.py3-none-any.whl.metadata
 Using cached humanfriendly-10.0-py2.py3-none-any.whl.metadata (9.2 kB)
Collecting mpmath<1.4.0,>=1.1.0 (from sympy->onnxruntime==1.18.1->-r ~/test/lambda/layers/onnx/requirements.txt (line 1))
 Obtaining dependency information for mpmath<1.4.0,>=1.1.0 from https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/43/e3/7d92a15f894aa0c9c4b49b8ee9ac9850d6e63b03c9c32c0367a13ae62209/mpmath-1.3.0-py3-none-any.whl.metadata
 Using cachedmpmath-1.3.0-py3-none-any.whl.metadata (8.6 kB)
Using cached onnxruntime-1.18.1-cp312-cp312-manylinux_2_27_x86_64.manylinux_2_28_x86_64.whl (6.8 MB)
Using cached numpy-1.26.4-cp312-cp312-manylinux_2_17_x86_64.manylinux2014_x86_64.whl (18.0 MB)
Using cached coloredlogs-15.0.1-py2.py3-none-any.whl (46 kB)
Using cached flatbuffers-24.3.25-py2.py3-none-any.whl (26 kB)
Using cached packaging-24.1-py3-none-any.whl (53 kB)
Using cached protobuf-5.27.2-cp38-abi3-manylinux2014_x86_64.whl (309 kB)
Using cached sympy-1.12.1-py3-none-any.whl (5.7 MB)
Using cached humanfriendly-10.0-py2.py3-none-any.whl (86 kB)
Using cached mpmath-1.3.0-py3-none-any.whl (536 kB)
Saved
/tmp/tmpt5hdp82u/onnxruntime-1.18.1-cp312-cp312-manylinux_2_27_x86_64.manylinux_2_28_x86_64.whl
Saved
/tmp/tmpt5hdp82u/numpy-1.26.4-cp312-cp312-manylinux_2_17_x86_64.manylinux2014_x86_64.whl
Saved
/tmp/tmpt5hdp82u/coloredlogs-15.0.1-py2.py3-none-any.whl
Saved
/tmp/tmpt5hdp82u/flatbuffers-24.3.25-py2.py3-none-any.whl
Saved
/tmp/tmpt5hdp82u/packaging-24.1-py3-none-any.whl
Saved
/tmp/tmpt5hdp82u/protobuf-5.27.2-cp38-abi3-manylinux2014_x86_64.whl
Saved
/tmp/tmpt5hdp82u/sympy-1.12.1-py3-none-any.whl
Saved
/tmp/tmpt5hdp82u/humanfriendly-10.0-py2.py3-none-any.whl
Saved
/tmp/tmpt5hdp82u/mpmath-1.3.0-py3-none-any.whl
Successfully downloaded onnxruntime numpy coloredlogs flatbuffers packaging protobuf sympy humanfriendly mpmath
'
2024-06-30 23:47:06,858 | pip stderr: b"WARNING: pip is being invoked by an old script wrapper. This will fail in a future version of pip.
Please see https://github.com/pypa/pip/issues/5599 for advice on fixing the underlying issue.
To avoid this problem you can invoke Python with '-m pip' instead of running pip directly.
"
2024-06-30 23:47:06,859 | Full dependency closure: {coloredlogs==15.0.1(wheel), flatbuffers==24.3.25(wheel), humanfriendly==10.0(wheel), protobuf==5.27.2(wheel), sympy==1.12.1(wheel), numpy==1.26.4(wheel), packaging==24.1(wheel), mpmath==1.3.0(wheel), onnxruntime==1.18.1(wheel)}
2024-06-30 23:47:06,860 | initial compatible: {coloredlogs==15.0.1(wheel), flatbuffers==24.3.25(wheel), humanfriendly==10.0(wheel), protobuf==5.27.2(wheel), sympy==1.12.1(wheel), numpy==1.26.4(wheel), mpmath==1.3.0(wheel), packaging==24.1(wheel)}
2024-06-30 23:47:06,861 | initial incompatible: {onnxruntime==1.18.1(wheel)}
2024-06-30 23:47:06,862 | Downloading missing wheels: {onnxruntime==1.18.1(wheel)}
2024-06-30 23:47:06,862 | calling pip download --only-binary=:all: --no-deps --platform manylinux2014_x86_64 --implementation cp --abi cp312 --dest /tmp/tmpt5hdp82u onnxruntime==1.18.1
2024-06-30 23:47:07,496 | pip stdout: b''
2024-06-30 23:47:07,496 | pip stderr: b"WARNING: pip is being invoked by an old script wrapper. This will fail in a future version of pip.
Please see https://github.com/pypa/pip/issues/5599 for advice on fixing the underlying issue.
To avoid this problem you can invoke Python with '-m pip' instead of running pip directly.
ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement onnxruntime==1.18.1 (from versions: none)
ERROR: No matching distribution found for onnxruntime==1.18.1
"
2024-06-30 23:47:07,497 | compatible wheels after second download pass: {coloredlogs==15.0.1(wheel), flatbuffers==24.3.25(wheel), humanfriendly==10.0(wheel), protobuf==5.27.2(wheel), sympy==1.12.1(wheel), numpy==1.26.4(wheel), mpmath==1.3.0(wheel), packaging==24.1(wheel)}
2024-06-30 23:47:07,499 | Build missing wheels from sdists (C compiling True): set()
2024-06-30 23:47:07,499 | compatible after building wheels (no C compiling): {coloredlogs==15.0.1(wheel), flatbuffers==24.3.25(wheel), humanfriendly==10.0(wheel), protobuf==5.27.2(wheel), sympy==1.12.1(wheel), numpy==1.26.4(wheel), mpmath==1.3.0(wheel), packaging==24.1(wheel)}
2024-06-30 23:47:07,500 | Build missing wheels from sdists (C compiling False): set()
2024-06-30 23:47:07,501 | compatible after building wheels (C compiling): {coloredlogs==15.0.1(wheel), flatbuffers==24.3.25(wheel), humanfriendly==10.0(wheel), protobuf==5.27.2(wheel), sympy==1.12.1(wheel), numpy==1.26.4(wheel), mpmath==1.3.0(wheel), packaging==24.1(wheel)}
2024-06-30 23:47:07,503 | Final compatible: {coloredlogs==15.0.1(wheel), flatbuffers==24.3.25(wheel), humanfriendly==10.0(wheel), protobuf==5.27.2(wheel), sympy==1.12.1(wheel), numpy==1.26.4(wheel), mpmath==1.3.0(wheel), packaging==24.1(wheel)}
2024-06-30 23:47:07,504 | Final incompatible: {onnxruntime==1.18.1(wheel)}
2024-06-30 23:47:07,505 | Final missing wheels: {onnxruntime==1.18.1(wheel)}
2024-06-30 23:47:07,948 | PythonPipBuilder:ResolveDependencies failed
Traceback (most recent call last):
 File "aws_lambda_builders/workflows/python_pip/actions.py", line 71, in execute
 File "aws_lambda_builders/workflows/python_pip/packager.py", line 157, in build_dependencies
 File "aws_lambda_builders/workflows/python_pip/packager.py", line 265, in build_site_packages
aws_lambda_builders.workflows.python_pip.packager.MissingDependencyError: {onnxruntime==1.18.1(wheel)}

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
 File "aws_lambda_builders/workflow.py", line 374, in run
 File "aws_lambda_builders/workflows/python_pip/actions.py", line 77, in execute
aws_lambda_builders.actions.ActionFailedError: {onnxruntime==1.18.1(wheel)}

Build Failed

What I've tried
If I create a virtual environment, with python 3.12, and install the same requirements.txt file, it installs without an issue.
I am using SAM CLI, version 1.119.0 and pip 24.1.1.

I had the same issue, and could solve it by

downgrading sam to version 1.94.0
using python3.11
fixing onnxruntime to 1.16.0

Probably there are more possible combinations that would work, but this one worked for me!

Using python3.11 and fixing onnxruntime to 1.16.0 solved my issue, with the latest version of SAM CLI
